# SQLite Calculate sum outside group by

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of a customer has spent over the total sales value.
I have calculated the total sales value per customer using sum() and group by, but after I use group by, I cannot differentiate the total sales value and the individual total for each sustomer.

is there anyway i could get around this?

i got to here so far and dont know what to do next:

```
select c.firstname ||' '|| c.lastname as 'Ful name', 
sum(total) as 'Sales value', 
/*something to calculate percentage*/,
from invoice i inner join customer c on i.customerid = c.customerid 
group by i.customerid order by sum(total) desc limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the simple sum over the entire table, move it into an independent subquery:

```
SELECT ...,
       sum(total) / (SELECT sum(total) FROM invoice)
FROM ...;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!